# How do i check if certain value is a string using Postman

Tags: json, api, testing, postman

I am trying to access a values inside keys using Postman and test what type of value it. The format i receive is Json and it is an array of few Json objects with the same Key and i am trying to test if the value matches the format ( for example if the value of a key is a string or int or...)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "accountNo": "1234567891234567",
        "companyCode": "Test",
        "apiKey": null,
        "name": "Test",
        "channel": "SFTP",
        "levelOne": 1,
        "levelTwo": 1,
        "levelThree": 1,
        "templateName": null,
        "codeFormat": "testni",
        "isAmountChangeAllowed": true,
        "isActive": false,
        "phoneNumber": "123456789",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "pdfFileUrl": "/app/",
        "interval": 0,
        "day": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "accountNo": "54345",
        "companyCode": "TEST",
        "apiKey": null,
        "name": "Testno Name",
        "channel": "SFTP",
        "levelOne": 1,
        "levelTwo": 1,
        "levelThree": 1,
        "templateName": null,
        "codeFormat": "testno",
        "isAmountChangeAllowed": true,
        "isActive": true,
        "phoneNumber": "312",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "pdfFileUrl": "/app/op",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": 5
    },
```

Error message i get is  "AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 5"

Comment: Is there anymore to that response? Its an array so you would need to use something like `pm.response.json()[0]` but without seeing more of the response and the test you wrote to get that error, it's all guess work. To check them all it would also need to loop through them.

Comment: Thank you, this is all i needed, didn't know i had to put index in front of response, now I know what and how to do it. Once again thank you.

Comment: No problem. Anytime you're working with an array `[ ]` you would need to do this.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thanks again.